# Replace all dates with new date format intelij

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there some way to automatically replace format of date strings.

Example I have:

"2022-09-25T16:00:00.000Z" want to replace with "2022-09-25T18:00:00+0200"

Comment: Are you trying to change timezones here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen basically want to add +2 hours and replace .000Z" to +0200" but the offeset i can replace it with basic replace.

Comment: UTC to OffsetDateTime. But OffsetDateTime still is not a country locale ZonedDateTime (summer time DST)

Comment: I can find all with this regex [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0:9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z, but not sure how to replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok one solution is to use regex for find:

```
([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T.*?)00(:[0-9]{2}:[0:9]{2}.*?).000Z
```

and for replace :

```
$102$3+0200
```

where

- $1 is group 1 till T
- 02 is the hour replacement for 00 (have to do this manually for all 24 hours)
- $2 is the group selection after hour till the .
- +0200 as a replacement for .000Z